# How do you store the click command line arguments/options for reference?

Tags: python, command-line-interface, python-click

New to click here so I'm still learning.  How do I store the click arguments/options in an object for later reference within my application?  I thought of just creating an object and returning it from the setup function, but it doesn't seem to work.  Here is what I did:

```
import click
import sys


class Cfg(object):
    component = ""
    command = ""
    obj = ""


my_cfg = Cfg()


@click.command()
@click.argument('component')
@click.argument("command")
@click.argument("obj")
def set_args(component, command, obj):
    cfg = Cfg()
    if component != "optdata":
        sys.stderr.write("Invalid option")
        sys.exit(1)
    else:
        cfg.component = component
        cfg.command = command
        cfg.obj = obj

    return cfg


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app_cfg = Cfg()
    app_cfg = set_args() # Never actually completes here. 
    print("Component = ", app_cfg.component, "Command = ", app_cfg.command, "Obj = ", app_cfg.obj)
```

There is some sort of exception raised in core.py which just does a sys.exit and doesn't raise any sort of actual error.

Answer (score 1):

Your design goes against the idea of Click: You're not supposed to treat "parsing the options" and "doing the work" as two separate steps:

```
import click

@click.command()
@click.argument("component", type=click.Choice(["optdata"]))
@click.argument("command")
@click.argument("obj")
def cli(component, command, obj):
    print("Component = ", component, "Command = ", command, "Obj = ", obj)
    # put your business logic here

if __name__ == "__main__":
    cli()
```

The pattern is to call the function that processes the command line options and then have that function call any other functionality.